# fitnesse: update test scenario file from fixture

Tags: continuous-integration, automated-tests, integration-testing, fitnesse

is it possible to find test scenario file from fixture, i want to update content.txt and use this update in future test runs. 
Idea :1st test run records data from application, other runs compares data with returned from application

Answer (score 0):

${PAGE_PATH}.${PAGE_NAME}  will generate path to current test from fitnesse root, put it into setup

Comment: I know it's an old thread - but just in case anyone reads it - could you please give more details?? how to get the path/name of the page - what does "put it into setup? mean?
thank you!